# A few questions about Qt pro-file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I want to locate generated Makefile into some another directory and use it from there.

Here is the part of my pro-file:

```
OBJECTS_DIR = build/Objects-files
MOC_DIR = build/Moc-files
RCC_DIR = build/Rcc-files

# Location of the binary file
DESTDIR = bin

MAKEFILE = build/Makefile
```

And with last line I got:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
Exited with code 2.
```

And second question, what variable sets the location of ui include files (for example `ui_mainwindow.h`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to run qmake in the directory where you want the Makefile to be generated, so you your case you would have to do

```
cd build
qmake ../your_project_file.pro
```

Regarding the location of the files generated by uic, you need to set the `UI_DIR` variables (or `UI_HEADERS_DIR`/`UI_SOURCES_DIR` if you want to place headers and implementations files in separate headers).